# Сделать не кликабельным div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, вообщем простой вопрос. Есть `div` блок, внутри которого `textarea`, ссылка, и пару картинок. Как проще всего сделать этот блок недееспособным? Чтобы при нажатии на ссылку к примеру, ничего не открывалось, ну и так же на `textarea`, чтобы нельзя было ничего писать.

Думал наложить поверх невидимый блок, но как мне кажется это примитивно.

Comment: Сделайте скриншот и вставьте картинкой.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` на контейнере

Comment: Сделать поверх невидимый блок — это не примитивно. В любом случае это лишь фронт-энд.

Comment: Не забудьте, что в форму можно попасть не только кликом мыши, тачем, но и табом, пропишите отрицательный табиндекс

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. В css `pointer-events: none;`
2. В js сделать обработчик события, возвращающий `false` (например, `addEventListener('click', function () { return false; });`)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте prevent default, или же css pointer-events: none; - сам сталкивался с такой же проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

Можно js-ом добавлять элементу в style
pointer-events: none;

```
var div_id = document.getElementById('div_id');

div_id.style.pointerEvents='auto'; //on click
div_id.style.pointerEvents='none'; //off click
```

Answer (score 1):

У любого элемента формы есть два состояния, которые ограничивают доступ к элементу или ввод данных, — блокирование (disabled) и только для чтения (readonly).

Когда к тегу  добавляется атрибут readonly, текстовое поле не может изменяться пользователем, в том числе вводиться новый текст или модифицироваться существующий.